# Deleting rows based on a date

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am deleting rows based on a date.

I am loading the entire sheet into an array and doing the evaluation and building a string containing the rows I want to delete.

```
Option Explicit

Sub arrmaker()
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Dim i_LastRow, i_LastColumn, i_FirstRow, ictr, ictr2, i_row, i_col As Long
Dim Da_Array(), Da_Other_Array(), Da_Third_Array, Da_Dates(), da_Names() As Variant
Dim Da_Builder() As String
Dim splitter() As String
Dim s_rows As String
Dim v_builder As Variant
Dim da_Range, rng_Deletes As Range
Dim prodhold As Long
Dim i_init, i_sec, i_Main As Long
Dim i_hold1, i_hold2, i_hold3 As Long

Sheets(1).Select

Dim da_date As Date
da_date = Date
ictr = 16
Sheets(1).Range("_FilterDatabase").Select
i_FirstRow = Sheets(1).Range("_FilterDatabase").Row
i_LastRow = Last(1, Sheets(1).Cells)
i_LastColumn = Last(2, Sheets(1).Cells)


i_FirstRow = Sheets(1).Range("_FilterDatabase").Row
i_LastColumn = Last(2, Sheets(1).Cells)
Sheets(1).Activate

Call Sort_Em(i_LastRow)
Da_Array = Range(Cells(i_FirstRow, 1), Cells(i_LastRow, i_LastColumn))
'i_FirstRow
s_rows = ""
For ictr = LBound(Da_Array) To UBound(Da_Array) - 1
    If ictr > i_FirstRow And Da_Array(ictr, 42) = Da_Array(ictr + 1, 42) And Da_Array(ictr, 1) = Da_Array(ictr + 1, 1) _
    And Da_Array(ictr, 40) <> Da_Array(ictr + 1, 40) Then
        splitter = Split(Da_Array(ictr, i_LastColumn), "-")
        If CDate(RetMonthNum(splitter(1)) & "/" & splitter(0) & "/" & splitter(2)) < da_date Then
            s_rows = s_rows & ictr + i_FirstRow & ":" & ictr + i_FirstRow & ","

        End If
    End If
Next ictr

s_rows = Left(s_rows, Len(s_rows) - 1)
v_builder = strChk(s_rows)

Set rng_Deletes = Range(v_builder(LBound(v_builder)))
For ictr = LBound(v_builder) + 1 To UBound(v_builder)
    Set rng_Deletes = Union(rng_Deletes, Range(v_builder(ictr)))
Next ictr
rng_Deletes.Select
Selection.Delete

Da_Array = Range(Cells(i_FirstRow, 1), Cells(i_LastRow, i_LastColumn))
Da_Other_Array() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Da_Array, 0, 42)
Sheets("tmp").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(UBound(Da_Other_Array), 1).Address).Value = Da_Other_Array
Sheets("tmp").Range("$A$1:$A$" & UBound(Da_Other_Array)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
i_LastRow = Last(1, Sheets("tmp").Cells)
Sheets("tmp").Activate
Da_Third_Array = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i_LastRow, 1))
ReDim Da_Builder(LBound(Da_Array) To UBound(Da_Array), 1 To UBound(Da_Array, 2) + 2 * UBound(Da_Third_Array))

For i_init = 1 To UBound(Da_Array, 2)
    Da_Builder(1, i_init) = Da_Array(1, i_init)
Next i_init
'MsgBox UBound(Da_Builder, 2)
i_hold1 = 0
For i_sec = 1 To UBound(Da_Third_Array)
i_hold2 = UBound(Da_Array, 2)
    Da_Builder(1, i_sec + i_hold1 + i_hold2) = Da_Third_Array(i_sec, 1)
       Da_Builder(1, i_sec + i_hold1 + 1 + i_hold2) = "cur"
    i_hold1 = i_hold1 + 1
Next i_sec

Sheets("tmp2").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(1, UBound(Da_Builder, 2)).Address).Value = Da_Builder

i_LastRow = Last(1, Sheets(2).Cells)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i_LastRow, 1))
da_Names = rng.Value
Sheets("hold").Select
Sheets("hold").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(UBound(Da_Array), UBound(Da_Array, 2)).Address) = Da_Array
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$25525").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Sheets("hold").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(1, UBound(Da_Builder, 2)).Address).Value = Da_Builder
i_LastRow = Last(1, Sheets("hold").Cells)
ictr2 = 2
prodhold = Cells(ictr2, 1)
For ictr = LBound(Da_Array) + 1 To UBound(Da_Array)
    If CLng(Da_Array(ictr, 1)) <> prodhold Then
        ictr2 = ictr2 + 1
        prodhold = Cells(ictr2, 1)
    End If
        Set rng = Worksheets("hold").UsedRange.Find(Da_Array(ictr, 42), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
       ' Set rng = Sheets("hold").Range("A1:A" & UBound(Da_Builder, 2)).Find(Da_Array(ictr, 42), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Cells(ictr2, rng.Column) = Da_Array(ictr, 48)
        Cells(ictr2, rng.Column + 1) = Da_Array(ictr, 49)

Next ictr
End Sub
```

This is fed to break the string into an array of strings, each less than 255:

```
Function strChk(s_rows) As Variant
Dim l_point, l_ctr, l_hold, l_start As Long
Dim OutArray() As String

l_ctr = 0
l_start = 1
l_point = 1
'ReDim Preserve OutArray(l_ctr)
Do While l_point <> 0
    If l_point - l_start > 255 Then
        ReDim Preserve OutArray(l_ctr)
            l_point = l_hold
            OutArray(l_ctr) = Mid(s_rows, l_start, l_point - l_start)
            l_ctr = l_ctr + 1
            l_start = l_point + 1
    Else
        l_hold = l_point
    End If
        l_point = InStr(l_point + 1, s_rows, ",")
Loop

strChk = OutArray
End Function
```

Is there a more efficient way to build a range for deletion, and if so, how would I go about it?

More on the delete criteria. If the date in column 55 is less than the current date, it needs to be deleted.

Note:

I cannot simply sort by date because there is an additional criterion.  I delete the row **only** if the current date is greater than the date on the sheet, **and** the version in column 42 has no previous versions.  So, if 42 has no previous version, then keep it even if expired.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "deleting rows based on a date".

Comment: @Raystafarian I could, but it takes up to five minutes to process doing it that way.  This way is faster, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: Is the sheet sorted by date so that all the rows to be deleted are contiguous? If so, then you could avoid creating the array by finding the first and last occurrences of what needs to be deleted and create your range with the first and last items.

Comment: @Raystafarian Original sorting before I took over: 8+ hours.  First iteration of my code: 15 minutes.  (sorting/deleting on the spreadsheet).  Second iteration of my code:  five minutes (identifying rows on the sheet and building the range to delete)  current time is about 50 seconds.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I edited the question, thanks!  the rows are NOT contiguous, and cannot be sorted to be so because there is additional criterion of a version number.  If there is no previous version number for the group, then I do not delete, even if expired.

Comment: How are you telling if there's a previous version?

Comment: @Raystafarian.  If the value in column 1 in the current row is the same as the value of column 1 in the next row, and if the value in column 42 in the current row is not the same as the value of column 42 in the next row and the date is before the current date, mark for deletion.

Comment: So are they in order of versions? That's why you can't sort or go from bottom to top?

Comment: @Raystafarian.  Yes, that is correct

Comment: That would be the way I'd describe it in the question then. It answers a lot about the structure of the cells and what other approaches are feasible. Unless you want to stick with the string of rows.

Comment: Just a note. When you have questions involving spreadsheet data, it's **really** useful to have a screenshot of the data (obfuscated if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule #1:

### Be explicit with your declarations:

You already have `Option explicit` which forces you to be explicit about variable **names** but not **types**. You have to declare a type for **every** variable.

This:

```
    Dim i_LastRow, i_LastColumn, i_FirstRow, ictr, ictr2, i_row, i_col As Long
```

Does not declare 7 `Long` Variables. It is actually doing this:

```
    Dim i_LastRow [As Variant], i_LastColumn [As Variant], i_FirstRow [As Variant], ictr [As Variant], ictr2 [As Variant], i_row [As Variant], i_col As Long
```

---

Rule #2:

### Naming

Names should be **Descriptive**, **Clear**, **Unambiguous** and **Concise**. In that order.

---

Your prefixes tell me **nothing** about your variables.

`i_LastRow` - what does the `i_` mean? I think you meant to use `l_` for `Long` but frankly, it's just distracting. If I see a variable called `lastRow` I already know it's going to be a row number.

Read [This](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) article on variable naming and why type-prefixes are a terrible idea.

---

**Stick to standard naming conventions**

Namely:

> **Local Variables:** Written in `camelCase`.
>
> `Dim localVariable As String`
>   includes method arguments.
>
> **Module / Global Variables:** Written in `PascalCase`.
>
> `Private ModuleVariable As String`
>   `Global PublicVariable As Long`
>
> **Method Names:** Verbs. Written in `PascalCase`
>
> `Private Function ReturnThisValue() As Long`
>   `Public Sub DoThisThing()`
>
> **Constants:** Written in `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE`
>
> `Public Const CONSTANT_VALUE As String = "This Value Never Changes"`

---

Some suggested substitutions:

`ictr` --> `counter` or just the standard `i, j, k`
`Da_Array()` --> `sheetArray()` or maybe `sheetData()`
`splitter` --> `splitHolder()`
`rng_deletes` --> `deleteRange`

**any** time you find yourself writing `variable, variable2, variable3` etc. It's a great sign that you need to **rethink your structure**. Probably involving some kind of loop.

---

Rule 3:

### Declare your variables as close to their usage as possible

In general, try to get as much information as possible as close to where it is used / applicable.

By the time I've finished reading the last of your variable declarations I've already forgotten most of the list. I don't want to have to keep scrolling back to the start of your procedure to find what things are. Just move them to where they'll actually be used:

```
    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = Date

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = Sheets(1)
    dataSheet.Activate

    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    firstRow = dataSheet.Range("_FilterDatabase").Row
    lastRow = Last(1, dataSheet.Cells)
    lastCol = Last(2, dataSheet.Cells)
```

Added bonus: the more you move things to where they're actually used, the more your code naturally separates into loosely-connected "sections" which can then easily be refactored into their own Subs/Functions.

### Refactoring

Take all the above (and the refactoring for your row deletion in my previous answer) and the first half of your code now looks like this:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = Date

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = Sheets(1)
    dataSheet.Activate

    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    firstRow = dataSheet.Range("_FilterDatabase").Row
    lastRow = Last(1, dataSheet.Cells)
    lastCol = Last(2, dataSheet.Cells)

    Dim ix As Long
    Dim deleteRange As Range, rCell As Range
    For ix = LBound(sheetarray, 1) To UBound(sheetarray, 1) - 1 '/ -1 because of Look-Ahead conditions in DeleteRow()
        If DeleteRow(sheetarray, ix, firstRow, currentDate) Then

            Set rCell = Cells(firstRow + ix, 1)
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then Set deleteRange = rCell Else Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, rCell)

        End If
    Next ix

    deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
```

hmm. suddenly this looks like its' own, completely separate thing.
**Maybe we should refactor it into its' own sub?**

```
Private Sub DeleteUndesiredRows()

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = Date

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = Sheets(1)
    dataSheet.Activate

    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    firstRow = dataSheet.Range("_FilterDatabase").Row
    lastRow = Last(1, dataSheet.Cells)
    lastCol = Last(2, dataSheet.Cells)

    Dim ix As Long
    Dim deleteRange As Range, rCell As Range
    For ix = LBound(sheetarray, 1) To UBound(sheetarray, 1) - 1 '/ -1 because of Look-Ahead conditions in DeleteRow()
        If DeleteRow(sheetarray, ix, firstRow, currentDate) Then

            Set rCell = Cells(firstRow + ix, 1)
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then Set deleteRange = rCell Else Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, rCell)

        End If
    Next ix

    deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

And now we can just call that at the start of our main sub and, should we need to change the row-deletion section **specifically**, we know exactly where to find it.

Comment: I would love to add more, but I have to sign off for today.

Comment: great advice.  I date back to the mainframe days, and we were taught to declare all of our variables at the top.  Thank you for your detailed and very thorough explanations of everything.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: I answered prior to [edit 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/123002/revisions) so some of this might be obsolete.**

---

Let's talk about some things first -

You didn't provide a `sub` that your procedure is in, but I will assume it's in a 'sub'. That being said, it doesn't seem that `Option Explicit` is turned on because you aren't *declaring your variables*.

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

Performance. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast it to the specific data type.

By not declaring variables, you could possibly be paying a penalty.

---

Speaking of **variables** - your naming scheme is confusing. Give your variables *meaningful names*. Something like `ictr` isn't very descriptive. It could just be `counter`. The same goes for `s_rows` and `v_builder` - I can see that they are *supposed* to be a string and a variant, but the name gives me no indication as to *what* they do. Why not `concatenatedRows` and `deletionArray`.

[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

It would end up more explanatory like

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadData()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim splitter As String
    Dim rangeToDelete As Range
    Dim splitRows As String
    Dim builtArray As Variant
    Dim myDate As Date

    For counter = LBound(dataArray) To UBound(dataArray) - 1
        If counter > firstRow And dataArray(counter, 42) = dataArray(counter + 1, 42) _
            And dataArray(counter, 1) = dataArray(counter + 1, 1) _
            And dataArray(counter, 40) <> dataArray(counter + 1, 40) Then
                splitter = Split(dataArray(counter, lastColumn), "-")
                If CDate(RetMonthNum(splitter(1)) & "/" & splitter(0) & "/" & splitter(2)) < myDate Then
                    splitRows = splitRows & counter + firstRow & ":" & counter + firstRow & ","
                End If
        End If
    Next counter

    splitRows = Left(splitRows, Len(splitRows) - 1)
    builtArray = strChk(splitRows)
    Set rangeToDelete = Range(builtArray(LBound(builtArray)))
        For counter = LBound(builtArray) + 1 To UBound(builtArray)
            Set rangeToDelete = Union(rangeToDelete, Range(builtArray(counter)))
        Next counter
    rangeToDelete.Select
    Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

You'll also note I changed the code structure. It's good practice to indent *all of your code* that way `Labels` will stick out as obvious.

Now I see that you are *selecting* the range to delete. Why not just `rangeToDelete.Delete`.

Be sure to avoid things like `.Select` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros .

---

For your function, you are requiring an input but it's being passed *byRef* by default. I don't see that it needs to go back, so you can just pass it `byVal` for increased speed.

```
Function CheckStringValue(ByVal splitRows as String) As Variant
```

The function - does it need to be a variant or could it be an array of strings?

---

Another good way to speed up your macro is to use `Application.Screenupdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Just be sure to return them to `True` and `xlAutomatic` and `True` before exiting the sub.

---

Within your function you put `Dim l_point, l_ctr, l_hold, l_start As Long` - this is only declaring `l_start` as `long` type. In VBA everything needs to be given a type -

```
Private Function strChk(splitRows) As String
    Dim l_point As Long
    Dim l_ctr As Long
    Dim l_hold As Long
    Dim l_start As Long
    Dim OutArray() As String
```

Your function doesn't appear to need a larger scope, so make it private. The other variables `l_` - I already went over naming so I won't beat a dead horse.

You are also using a delimiter string, why not make it a constant?

```
Private Function CheckStringValue(ByVal splitRows As String) As String
    Dim delimitPoint As Long
    Dim arrayCounter As Long
    Dim hold As Long
    Dim startPoint As Long
    Dim OutArray() As String
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","

    arrayCounter = 0
    startPoint = 1
    delimitPoint = 1

    'ReDim Preserve OutArray(arrayCounter)
    Do While delimitPoint <> 0
        If delimitPoint - startPoint > 255 Then
            ReDim Preserve OutArray(arrayCounter)
                delimitPoint = hold
                OutArray(arrayCounter) = Mid(splitRows, startPoint, delimitPoint - startPoint)
                arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                startPoint = delimitPoint + 1
        Else
            hold = delimitPoint
        End If
            delimitPoint = InStr(delimitPoint + 1, splitRows, DELIMITER)
    Loop

    CheckStringValue = OutArray
End Function
```

---

Now everything is much more legible and speed has been increased if you've changed the `Application` attributes.

It looks like in the main sub you're using another function `splitter` - what is that? I also don't see where `da_Date` is assigned?

Comment: Option explicit is on, just didn't show that part, the whole procedure is about 4 times as long as what I posted.

Comment: It could be an array of strings. The previous code was taking 8+ hours. I threw this together to address an emergency,  so it's not my best.

Comment: No worries, I've definitely had worse.

Comment: @RichardU If It's only 4 times as long, you could just post the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I answered prior to [edit 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/123002/revisions) so some of this might be obsolete.**

---

@Raystafarian has touched on the horribly obfuscated naming, so I won't repeat that advice.

This whole building a string array of range references is **entirely** unnecesary. Just build your `rng_deletes` union as you go:

```
'/ Note the conversion of "ictr" to "ix". Personally I like ix, iy, iz etc. for index iterators but that's just a personal preference.
'/ Also, "Da_Array" --> "sheetArray", "i_FirstRow" --> "firstRow"

For ix = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray) - 1
    If ix > firstRow And sheetArray(ix, 42) = sheetArray(ix + 1, 42) And sheetArray(ix, 1) = sheetArray(ix + 1, 1) _
    And sheetArray(ix, 40) <> sheetArray(ix + 1, 40) Then

        splitter = Split(sheetArray(ix, i_LastColumn), "-")
        If CDate(RetMonthNum(splitter(1)) & "/" & splitter(0) & "/" & splitter(2)) < da_date Then

            If rng_Deletes Is Nothing Then Set rng_Deletes = Cells(firstRow + ix, 1) Else Set rng_Deletes = Union(rng_Deletes, Cells(firstRow + ix, 1))

        End If

    End If
Next ix

rng_Deletes.EntireRow.Delete
```

And immediately the other half of you code can be removed.

---

> ```
> LBound(sheetArray)
> ```

This is **implicitly** doing `Lbound(sheetArray, 1)`. Never let your code do things implicitly, be explicit:

```
For ix = LBound(sheetArray, 1) To UBound(sheetArray, 1) - 1
```

---

Now, why `- 1`? Off-by-one errors are some of the most ubiquitous, difficult programming problems. If you need to add `+-1` modifiers, always leave a note explaining **why**:

```
For ix = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray) - 1 '/ -1 because of Look-Ahead conditions
```

It takes 2 seconds but will save you (or somebody else) from making costly mistakes and errors down the line.

---

Now, this:

> ```
>     If ix > firstRow And sheetArray(ix, 42) = sheetArray(ix + 1, 42) And sheetArray(ix, 1) = sheetArray(ix + 1, 1) _
>     And sheetArray(ix, 40) <> sheetArray(ix + 1, 40) Then
>
>             splitter = Split(sheetArray(ix, i_LastColumn), "-")
>             If CDate(RetMonthNum(splitter(1)) & "/" & splitter(0) & "/" & splitter(2)) < da_date Then
> ```

is messy and difficult to read/understand. You should have your delete check as a separate piece of business logic. Because you need **all** of these conditions to be met for a row to be deleted, you can also short-circuit after each check if it's false for a performance increase:

```
    For ix = LBound(sheetarray) To UBound(sheetarray) - 1
        If DeleteRow(sheetarray, ix, firstRow, thresholdDate) Then

            If rng_Deletes Is Nothing Then Set rng_Deletes = Cells(firstRow + ix, 1) Else Set rng_Deletes = Union(rng_Deletes, Cells(firstRow + ix, 1))

        End If
    Next ix

    rng_Deletes.EntireRow.Delete
```

With:

```
Private Function DeleteRow(ByRef dataArray As Variant, ByVal ix As Long, ByVal firstRow As Long, ByVal thresholdDate As Date) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim splitter As Variant

    result = False
    If ix > firstRow Then
        If sheetarray(ix, 42) = sheetarray(ix + 1, 42) Then
            If sheetarray(ix, 1) = sheetarray(ix + 1, 1) Then
                If sheetarray(ix, 40) <> sheetarray(ix + 1, 40) Then

                    splitter = Split(sheetarray(ix, i_LastColumn), "-")
                    If CDate(RetMonthNum(splitter(1)) & "/" & splitter(0) & "/" & splitter(2)) < thresholdDate Then

                        result = True

                    End If

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    DeleteRow = result

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Yes, it's messy, I'm in the process of cleaning it up.